# How to automatically run a google-app-script in my case? Is setting a trigger is enough?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that loads the (File name, URL, created and last modified) into my [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YW1eKia_fiCce7XKk1NSZvsx_cLizLM4gBdm8eKsZcM/edit#gid=2103593653) (Links tab). I used that tab to lookup all the corresponding URLs to the other 4 tabs(North,South,East,West) specifically in column F. My question is how can the script automatically run instantly so that the 'Links' tab is updated without triggering manually the 'run' button. The function of my script is to load all the data information in this [drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-2cWUKgEfm9RVpaTkJFQU9zZzA). All I want to the 'Links' tab is to be updated instantly whenever I uploaded an image to the said drive.

Here's the script I'm currently running:

```
//GLOBAL VARIABLES

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheets()[0];
var listCell = 'B1';
var idRange = 'A2:B2';
var idCell = 'B2';


function list() {

    var arr, files, file, data, sheet;

    arr = [["FILE NAME", "URL", "CREATED", "LAST MODIFIED"]];
    files = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B-2cWUKgEfm9RVpaTkJFQU9zZzA")
        .getFiles()
    while (files.hasNext()) {
        file = files.next();
        arr.push([file.getName(), file.getUrl(), file.getDateCreated(), file.getLastUpdated(), ]);
    }
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
        .getSheetByName('Links').getRange(1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length)
        .setValues(arr)
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can use a trigger to run the script automatically. I suggest you to check this [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable), it will let an Apps Script to run a function automatically when a certain event, such as opening a document, occurs. Installable triggers offer more flexibility than simple triggers, they can call services that require authorization, they offer several additional types of events including time-driven (clock) triggers, and they can be controlled programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive doesn't allow (for the moment) to set triggers for Drive events (like uploading, deleting or editing files).

But you can set a Time-driven Trigger for your function with 1 minute period (the highest frequency) in Script Editor by pressing the button [Current project's triggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thkMU.jpg).

Your problem could be partially solved if you have G Suite account. With G Suite you are able to upload files via Google Forms. And in that case you are able to add a Trigger for Form submit event.